# Replace regexp capture-group in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Quick question: I have a regexp, `^(?:\b[A-Z]+\b\s+)+(.*)\d{8}`, that gives two capture groups. I would like to replace capture group 1 with a whitespace. Is that possible?

If I do replace with: `\1` it replaces `TEST TESTER Hello, world. Another word here. 75793250` -> with `Hello, world. Another word here`. I want this result: `TEST TESTER 75793250`. Replacing the `\1` with a whitespace.

Comment: Um, there's is only one capture group as far as I see...? `(?: ...)` is a non-capturing group.

Comment: I thought it had two, 0 and 1? Group 0 is the full match? Anyhow I would like to replace the group that Notepad++ calls 1 with a whitespace.

Comment: If I do replace with: `\1` it replaces `TEST TESTER Hello, world. Another word here. 75793250` -> with `Hello, world. Another word here`. I want this result: `TEST TESTER 75793250`. Replacing the `\1` with a whitespace.

Comment: This `\1` doesn't work for me in the latest version of Notepad++ however I could get it to work using `$0` instead. It seems they changed the group replacement syntax.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Try using:

```
^((?:\b[A-Z]+\b\s+)+)(?:.*)(\d{8})
```

And replace with:

```
\1\2
```

Comment: @Kaah You're welcome! :) Also, reminded me to update my notepad version! I had 6.1.8 on xD

Answer (score 12):

Do it this way:

Regex: `^(\b[A-Z]+\b\s+)+(?:.*)(\d{8})`

Replace with: `\1 \2`

Comment: Thanks, but that gives `Invalid regular expression` in Notepad++ 6.3.3. Please revise Anirudh.

Comment: This regex will return `TESTER  75793250` since capturing a repeated group will only give you the last string it matches. Another example: replacing string `abcd` with a regex `(.)+` and a replace string `\1` will result in the string `d`

Comment: "Why would you do that."? Because OP didn't know, that's why they asked the question. Snark like this doesn't do anyone any good.

Answer (score 0):

Building Groups with `(?<1>....),(?<2>....)`, for substitution using `\1 \2`