# Trying to get v. simple Regex to work on XML file

Tags: regex, xml, sublimetext2, notepad++

This is my snippet of XML (the actual full file is 6964 lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchema Location="http://www.gstatic.com/localfeed/local_feed.xsd">
<language>en</language>
<id>43927</id>
<cell1>Andover House</cell1>
<cell2>28-30 Camperdown</cell2>
<cell3>Great Yarmouth</cell3>
<cell4>NR30 3JB</cell4>
<cell5>GB</cell5>
<cell6>52.6003767</cell6>
<cell7>1.7339649</cell7>
<cell8>+44 1493843490</cell8>
<category>British</cell9>
<cell10>http://contentadmin.livebookings.com/dynamaster/image_archive/original/f24c60a52e7ac0874be57e51bce30726.jpg</cell10>
<cell11>http://www.bookatable.co.uk/andover-house-great-yarmouth-norfolk</cell11>
```

For each category tag in the above snippet, I would simply like to add this text: `Restaurant -` (with one whitespace after the hyphen)

So the final result will be:

`<category>Restaurants - British</category>`

I am very new to Regex and find it very difficult, so this is what I've tried so far: https://regex101.com/r/yY5jB6/2

It looks like it is working in Regex 101 but when I bring it into a text editor like Sublime 2 (on Mac) and Notepad ++ (on Windows) using find/replace (specifying regex in settings), it says it can't find anything. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Notepad++ uses `\1` and not `$1` for a matching group. See the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392392/replace-regexp-capture-group-in-notepad

Comment: thanks @Rossiar just tried that and it didn't work. Same response: "Replace: no occurrence was found"

Comment: is your initial input really `<category>British</cell9>` with cell9??

Comment: Sorry Rossiar, my bad, made a silly mistake - that solution is working now in Notepad++, thanks! (not sure why it wasn't working in Sublime tho)

Comment: @h3n my bad, it should have been </category> end tag too. But solution from Rossiar is working now in Notepad++ Thanks again!

Comment: in your example, why do you need regexp then? just search for `<category>` and replace it with `<category>Restaurants - `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NotePad++ uses `\1` instead of `$1`, if you change your substitution from
`$1Restaurants -` to `\1Restaurants -` then it should work. (sourced from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392392/replace-regexp-capture-group-in-notepad))

Answer (score 0):

if you search for

```
<category>([^<]*)<\/.*>
```

and replace it with

```
<category>Restaurants - $1</category>
```

it would even work with your strange input that contains a `</item9>` tag.