# Notepad++ How to replace a term by regular expression without replacing the whole selection

Tags: regex, notepad++

So that when I'm searching for:

```
 ,[A-Z"]
```

in

```
Q3,"Language, speech and grammar"
Q4,The Media
Q4.1,The Media:- Books
Q4.2,The Media:- Newspapers etc.
Q4.3,"The Media:- TV, Radio and Cinema"
S,Sociobility GENERAL
S1,"SOCIAL ACTIONS, STATES AND PROCESSES"
```

I can replace just the "," or even the following capital letter, but not the whole selection. Using the replace function to substitute ":" for the expression will produce:

```
Q3:Language, speech and grammar"
Q4:he Media
Q4.1:he Media:- Books
Q4.2:he Media:- Newspapers etc.
Q4.3:The Media:- TV, Radio and Cinema"
S:ociobility GENERAL
S1:SOCIAL ACTIONS, STATES AND PROCESSES"
```

Comment: Please show a better sample of data which shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace regexp capture-group in Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392392/replace-regexp-capture-group-in-notepad)

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html

Comment: Thank you for the reference material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for capture groups - use a find string of `,([A-Z"])` and replace of `:\1`, and it works with your sample data.

Verified with Notepad++ v7.2.2.

Answer (score -1):

I Dont think its possible to add constraints to find and replace in Notepad++.

An alternate solution would be to copy the contents into another text editor which supports Find And Replace changes.

Comment: No, you are mistaken; it is possible.