# Notepad++ regex remover whatever after this text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this list below:

```
userId,username,full_name,is_private,follower_count,following_count,media_count,biography,hasProfilePic,external_url,email,contact_phone_number,address_street,isbusiness,Engagement %,MostRecentPostDate,AvgLikes,AvgComments,category,businessJoinDate,businessCountry,businessAds,countryCode,cityName


="2992534482",that_boi_coop97,kenny cooper,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
    ="1523975290",akseli_vira,Akseli Vira,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
    ="21160216082",olive.theboxer,Olive,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
    ="1602052187",rburkey89,Rachel Jones,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
    ="179855282",kogdevo,Big Slime,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
    ="182611528",lashladyyb_,Houston Lash Tech‼️,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
    ="11597193347",_elgranalex,A.$.H,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
    ="17908029725",wearehappilymarriednow,ihavemyownhusbandnosharing,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
    ="1279900164",frank_manning_87,Frank,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,
```

I would like to get the Usernames only as below:

```
that_boi_coop97
akseli_vira
olive.theboxer
rburkey89
kogdevo
_elgranalex
wearehappilymarriednow
frank_manning_87
```

I've tried to Search for: ",*$ and replace with nothing but giving me replace: no occurrence was found.

I wish somebody who can help me to find the right Regex to extract the Usernames only.

Thank you.
regards.

Answer (score 1):

This will capture the second column, in your case it is the usernames

```
^[^,]*,([^,]*),.*$
```

Then replace with `\1`

Make sure to select Regular expression in the Search Mode

Explanation:
Match the start of the line `^`, then as many chars that are not a comma `[^,]*`, then match a comma `,`, then start capturing `(`, capturing the sequence of anything that is not a comma `[^,]*`, stop capturing `)`, then match a comma `,` (can be ommited), then match the remainder of the line `.*$`.

The \1 is then used to replace the first captured match.

Comment: \1 works for me, and for others. Never tried $1. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392392/replace-regexp-capture-group-in-notepad/17392520

Comment: Sorry ... need to have more coffee. `\1` does of course work, I was thinking of something else (although `$1` does work in notepad too)

Comment: `\1` is an old notation (kept for compatibility) it should be used in regex only as a backreference, See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068936/372239