# notepad++ how to replace all [, ] with (, )?

Tags: arrays, regex, 2d, notepad++

how to replace all [,] with (,) in notepad++ with regex? like this:

```
  abc[1, 2]; => abc(1, 2);
  abc[EDGE, 2]; => abc(EDGE, 2);
  abc[EDGE, INDEX]; => abc(EDGE, INDEX);
  ...
  abc[EDGE, otherArray[1]]; => abc[EDGE, otherArray[1]);
  abc[array[VERT], other[INDEX]]; => abc(array[VERT], other[INDEX]);
```

Edit:

the `,` matters (it's 2d array), these should be excluded:

```
    abc[1]; <--- ignore
    abc[1, 2, 3]; <-- ignore
    abc[index]; <-- ignore
    abc[otherArray[EDGE], 2, 8]; <-- ignore
```

Thank you.

Edit2:

Hi Substitue, your answer works almost perfect, except this line:

```
if (test[0])
{
    triangles.push_back(tris[i, V1]); // <-- fail here, it gets 'test[0]' involved
    triangles.push_back(tris[i, V2]);
    triangles.push_back(tris[i, V3]);
}
```

Comment: To your edit, are you asking to only capture even groups or only groups of 2? Your examples above are 2 elements in length while the don’t capture examples are 1 and 3; leaving abc[1,2,3,4] ambiguous.

Comment: as you can see in the examples, it's a 2d array, so two elements only, other cases are ignored. i overloaded operator(int, int) in c++  to simulate [,] in c#.

Comment: I've edited the original answer that should work for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture the content between `[]`.
`\[(.*)\]`

To address the need to only match the above examples, you can use
`\[([^,\n]+,[^,\n]+)\]`

See: https://regex101.com/r/tfY6cs/1

In your replace field you can then use
`\(\1\)` to put `(<captured group1>)`

If you need to capture `[]` recursively you have two options.

The easy option is to just repeat the search/replace.

The hard option is to rewrite the regex to be recursive.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17392520/19192256

Comment: Almost perfect, but there is a flaw, see my original post (Edit 2), it looks i can't put code here.

Comment: Hi, 21k. You can adjust it to this `\[([^,\n]+,[^,\n]+)\]` which should handle those pesky newlines between [ and ].

Comment: Your answer helps a lot and saves a lot of work. The only failure case is this : `process(points[1].coords, points[2].coords, points[3].coords, points[4].coords);` but it doesn't matter, I just need to skip them (a few).

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
\[(\w+(\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*])*\s*,\s*\w+(\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*])*)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0hKPWz/1). Replace with `\($1\)` (round parentheses need escaping since they are special in Boost regex replacements).

*Details*:

- `\[` - `[` char
- `(\w+(\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*])*\s*,\s*\w+(\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*])*)` - Group 1:

  - `\w+` - one or more word chars
  - `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*])*` - zero or more substrings between paired nested square brackets
  - `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\w+(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?-1))*])*)?` - one or more word chars and then zero or more substrings between paired nested square brackets
- `]` - a `]` char.

Notepad++ demo:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer that fits a lot more use cases, but for this particular question they wanted specifically something for Notepad++; I’m not sure how substitution works in Notepad++ in regards to find and replace.

Comment: @Substitute This answer is for Notepad++. See the screenshot. Only the expected 5 out of 9 strings are replaced.

Comment: These patterns are awesome :-) ++

Comment: Your answer is more accurate, it successfully identifies this case: `process(points[1].coords, points[2].coords, points[3].coords, points[4].coords);` which fails in above answer. Awesome!